# Why does installing a cocoapod create missing files in xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode7

I installed cocoapods on my machine.

I added a podfile to my project and then ran `pod install`.

The resulting file structure that xcode picks up, seems to contain a number of missing files in Frameworks and Products.
[image]

Is this expected behaviour? I deleted the pod files and directory and recreated them again using `pod install`. Same result. I started a new project and did the same. Same result.

If this is expected behaviour, what am I looking at here? Why are there missing files? (if indeed that is what the files being red means).

I don't yet know what the "Products" or ".framework" files are for.

My podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.1'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'Hospital Demo' do
    pod 'HLSpriteKit'
end
```

(aside: It's not causing my an build errors, and the app so far runs fine. Don't know if it makes any difference, but I'm using swift.)

Comment: Those are *Products* aren't they?  If so they are what would be built.  Anyway, if it's not actually causing an error I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: "Products" are a new concept to me. My background is web development. I don't understand, and I want to understand. Sure, I could not worry about them, but I also want to know.

Comment: Do you understand about compiling source files to object files and then linking object files + library and frameworks into executables or dynamic libraries?  If not, then you should search around as it's important to understand.  Anyway *products* would be the "executables or dynamic libraries".

Comment: Yeah. Right that makes sense. It still doesn't explain why they are in xcode but red though.